# what is a 'C-like' module in C++? and how to implement it?

Tags: c++, c

I am new to C++, and I have an assignment need to be done in c like module. According to my professor, 'C-like' module has no class is being written, only a non-member (C-like) function.
my assignment is to write a C-style module sort.h & sort.cpp with a function sort() in the .h file. sort() accepts an array of integer and sort the array using bubble sort. how do I implement this if no class is involved?

Comment: have you not written functions yet?  If not there should be a chapter or two about them in your book you can consult to see how you can write non-OOP code.

Comment: Why is not using a class a problem for you? Surely that makes it easier not harder.

Comment: Search your favorite C++ reference for "free standing function".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C++ language, you can have functions that are *outside* of a class, called *free standing* functions.

Sort.hpp:

```
#ifndef SORT_HPP
#define SORT_HPP

#include <vector>

void my_sort(std::vector& v);

#endif
```

Sort.cpp:

```
#include "sort.hpp"

void my_sort(std::vector& v)
{
  // Insert code to sort the vector here.
}
```

It is a C-like module because the C language doesn't support classes and member functions.